# The current path, didn't match any of these - Django

Tags: django

the page `http://127.0.0.1:8000/category.html/` throws a 404,
saying

```
Using the URLconf defined in ddblog2.urls, Django tried these URL 
patterns, in this order:

admin/
^ [name='index']
^ category [name='category']
The current path, category.html/, didn't match any of these.
```

[image]

ddblog2/ddblog2/urls.py is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

ddblog2/blog/urls.py is as follows:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'), 
    path('category/', views.category, name = 'category')
]
```

ddblog2/blog/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})

def category(request):
    return render(request, 'category.html', {})
```

'blog' has been added to the INSTALLED_APPS

how do I correct this error?

Comment: The URL pattern is `category/` and not `category.html/`. Also why not use `path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),` for the blog app urls instead of `r'^'`?

Comment: Try http://127.0.0.1:8000/category

Comment: @Rajan yeah my mistake. Got it.

Answer (score -1):

you need add the html to ddblog2/blog/templates/blog/